# Is there an example WebSockets for Qt?

Tags: qt, websocket

Is there an example WebSockets for Qt?

Comment: @charles: please do not remove relevant tags if you do not have more relevant. Also, we lost all that tagwiki information now. Please be more careful next time. Qt and websockets mean pretty much QtWebsockets these days as it became part of Qt proper. Even if it was not, there is a meta discussion about being OK to add tags based on the relevant answers.

Comment: @FinalContest, tags are for *questions*, not answers.  This is **not** a question about a specific library mentioned in an answer, it's a question about websockets in Qt.

Comment: @FinalContest, I'm not saying that the tag shouldn't exist, I'm saying that having **this** question be the **only** one with the tag isn't appropriate.  This is a library recommendation question anyway, and is thus off-topic.  There are [at least a few](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=qtwebsocket) other questions  that the tag could and *probably should* exist on.  The edit happened so long ago that I don't remember if they existed at the time.

Comment: @FinalContest, don't take it so personally, my friend.  We're both trying to improve the site, right?  We just disagree about one specific tag added to one specific question.  Given the age of some of the questions actually asking about qtwebsocket, and when the tag was added here, it looks like *I erred in removing the tag and not adding it to the relevant questions instead*.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 3):

You can also have a look at [QtWebSockets](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebSockets). QtWebSockets can be used both for client and server applications, and passes the Autobahn test suite.

Answer (score 1):

QWebView inside of QtWebKit supports the use of Web Sockets (from the HTML5 standard). I have used them multiple times without any issue.

Comment: Can you possibly share the source code to get us newbies started?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example. Here is the code:

inspection_server.hpp:

```
#ifndef __INSPECTION_SERVER_HPP__
#define __INSPECTION_SERVER_HPP__

#include <QWebSocketServer>
#include <QWebSocket>
#include <QObject>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class InspectionServer;

typedef std::shared_ptr<QWebSocketServer> QWebSocketServerPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<QWebSocket> QWebSocketPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<InspectionServer> InspectionServerPtr;

class InspectionServer: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QWebSocketServerPtr websocketServer;
    QList<QWebSocketPtr> clients;

public:
    InspectionServer(uint16_t port);

signals:
    void closed();

private slots:
    void onNewConnection();
    void processTextMessage(const QString& message);
    void socketDisconnected();

};

#endif
```

inspection_server.cpp:

```
#include "inspection_server.hpp"

#include <QDebug>

InspectionServer::InspectionServer(uint16_t port)
    : websocketServer(new QWebSocketServer(QStringLiteral("Inspection server"), QWebSocketServer::NonSecureMode))
{
    if(this->websocketServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
    {
        QObject::connect(websocketServer.get(), SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("InspectionServer: failed to listen");
    }
}

void InspectionServer::onNewConnection()
{
    qInfo() << "InspectionServer::onNewConnection";
    QWebSocketPtr socket(this->websocketServer->nextPendingConnection());

    QObject::connect(socket.get(), SIGNAL(textMessageReceived(const QString&)), this, SLOT(processTextMessage(const QString&)));
    QObject::connect(socket.get(), SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(socketDisconnected()));

    this->clients.append(socket);
}

void InspectionServer::processTextMessage(const QString& message)
{
    qInfo() << "InspectionServer::processTextMessage: " << message;
}

void InspectionServer::socketDisconnected()
{
    qInfo() << "InspectionServer::socketDisconnected";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "inspection_server.hpp"

#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    InspectionServer server(1234);

    return app.exec();
}
```

And here is how to test that in your Web browser:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onClick="initWebSocket();">Connect</button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="messageInput">
<button onClick="sendMessage();">Send message</button>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

var websocket = null;

function initWebSocket()
{
    websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234");
}

function sendMessage()
{
    websocket.send(document.getElementById("messageInput").value);
}

</script>
```

This is a good link for reference:
http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebsockets.git/tree/examples/websockets/echoserver